# Passing GLM's vector types to OpenGL via glUniform

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

### Background

I'm currently writing a wrapper around OpenGL's [`glUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) functions in C++ in an effort to make them type safe. I have a bunch of `set_uniform` functions that are overloaded to accept either the OpenGL PODs (`GLint`, `GLuint`, `GLfloat`) or any of the GLM vector and matrix types.

I thought it had all been straight forward so far but then I hit a problem with boolean types. GLSL provides provides `bool`, `bec2`, `bvec3` and `bvec4` so I must provide a `set_uniform` overload for `GLboolean` as well as the GLM boolean vector types.

According to the OpenGL manual there is no `glUniform` function that accepts either a `GLboolean` or a pointer to a `GLboolean` array. I must pass either `GLint`, `GLuint` or `GLfloat` and the driver will do the conversion for me.

> Either the i, ui or f variants may be used to provide values for uniform variables of type bool, bvec2, bvec3, bvec4, or arrays of these. The uniform variable will be set to false if the input value is 0 or 0.0f, and it will be set to true otherwise.

Converting `GLboolean` to `GLint` before passing is easy enough but the GLM vector types are proving more difficult. The deeper I go into the implementation the more worried I get about this library.

### Problem

The recommended way to pass a GLM vector type to OpenGL is to use `glm::value_ptr`:

```
glm::bvec3 v(true, true, false);
glUniform3iv(some_uniform_id, 1, glm::value_ptr(v));
```

I have a number of problems with this code.

First, [`glm::bvec3` is implemented as a struct of 3 `bool`s](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00093_source.html#l00253) (not `GLboolean` but C++ `bool`). I don't believe I should pass it directly since `glUniform3iv` is expecting a `void` pointer to some `GLint`s. The C++ spec gives no guarantee over the size of a `bool`. This means `glUniform3iv` is potentially reading garbage for the second and third component, or worse, it's actually reading past the end of the array.

To correct this I convert from `glm::bvec3` to `glm::ivec3` before passing to OpenGL:

```
glm::bvec3 bv(true, true, false);
glm::ivec3 iv = bv;
glUniform3iv(some_uniform_id, 1, glm::value_ptr(iv));
```

I'm not 100% happy with this since `glm::ivec3` has a value type of `glm::detail::mediump_int_t` which is a `typedef` for `int` rather than `GLint` but maybe this can be chalked up to 'the library designer knows the sizes are the same'.

The second and more major problem is that `glm::value_ptr` is [just passing the address of the first `struct` member](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.0/api/a00099_source.html#l00033) and treating the `struct` as an `array` with no regard to padding.

Am I missing something here? The GLM library is very widely used alongside OpenGL, it's even listed on Khronos' own wiki. Yet the function it provides for passing its structures to OpenGL, namely `glm::value_ptr`, makes no effort to ensure the types it's passing are actually the same size as the types OpenGL expects as well as completely disregarding any padding that may exist. Is the GLM library doing some hidden trickery with regard to type sizes and struct padding so that the data sent to OpenGL is valid or does this library have some serious fundamental problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the GLM library doing some hidden trickery with regard to type sizes and struct padding so that the data sent to OpenGL is valid or does this library have some serious fundamental problems?

Neither. It's simply making the [same assumptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38428666/734069) that everyone else does about the behavior of struct layouts and pointer arithmetic.

The C++ standard does not allow `value_ptr` to work; it is clearly undefined behavior. But it is also a commonly used technique for dealing with such things. Lots of real, functional code out there assumes that a `struct { int x; int y;};` can be considered equivalent to an `int[2]`. And under most C++ implementations, this will all function as expected.

When dealing with low-level programming, it is not unreasonable to make assumptions of this nature.

---

> I'm not 100% happy with this since `glm::ivec3` has a value type of `glm::detail::mediump_int_t` which is a `typedef` for `int` rather than `GLint` but maybe this can be chalked up to 'the library designer knows the sizes are the same'.

That has nothing to do with it. While GLM is called "OpenGL Mathematics", it has no dependency on OpenGL *itself*. As such, it has no access to `GLint` or any other OpenGL-defined type.

So you can either assume that `ivec3`'s `value_type` will be the same type as `GLint` (you can even write `static_assert`s to verify it) or you can make your own variation. After all, GLM is templated:

```
using gl_ivec3 = glm::tvec<GLint, 3>;
...
glm::gl_ivec3 iv = bv;
glUniform3iv(some_uniform_id, 1, glm::value_ptr(iv));
```

Comment: So the implementation of value_ptr is basically adhering to a de facto standard even if it isn't 100% portable? Makes sense though it contradicts the GLM website that it's a "platform independent library" and it supports "Any conform C++98 or C++11 compiler". I'll do as you say and typedef the GLM structs with OGL value types. It's madness to make a library for interoperability with OGL but not provide data in the format OGL expects. There's no need for any dependency. C++ provides sized types and the sizes OGL expects [are easily available](http://khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Type).